# asp.net how to print dynamic table

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this below Literal to show my dynamic table

```
<div id="Print">     
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal> 
</div>
```

and i place a imagebutton to print

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" 
ImageUrl="~/Image/Print_Icon_Design.jpg" Height="25px" 
Width="27px" style="margin-left:20px" OnClientClick="CallPrint"/>
```

and i have below code to print but it is not working can you please help

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function CallPrint(Print) {
        var prtContent = document.getElementById(Print);
        var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=400,height=400,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
        WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
        WinPrint.document.close();
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
</script>
```

Comment: i corrected but it is still not working

Comment: try adding parameter in the image button: OnClientClick="CallPrint('somevalue')", since your js function have one argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the parameter Print for the function and add change the getElementById

```
var prtContent = document.getElementById('Print');
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put `Print` inside quotes and your function is missing the final curly bracket.
Also, you don't need the Print parameter (since you're not passing it in from the ImageButton and you're already retrieving it using getElementById():

```
function CallPrint() {
            var prtContent = document.getElementById("Print");
            var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=400,height=400,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
            WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
            WinPrint.document.close();
            WinPrint.focus();
            WinPrint.print();
}
```

Comment: i corrected with the brackets but it still does nothing,any idea

Comment: the code is fine, it should work. Are there any errors in javascript console? Can you show the complete HTML output?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function CallPrint() {
                var prtContent = document.getElementById('Print');
                var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=400,height=400,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
                WinPrint.document.open();
                WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
                WinPrint.document.close();
                WinPrint.focus();
                WinPrint.print();
                return false;
}
 </script>
```

and

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" 
                        ImageUrl="~/Image/Print_Icon_Design.jpg" Height="25px" 
            Width="27px" style="margin-left:20px" OnClientClick="return CallPrint()"/>
```

return false to OnClientClick will prevent postback

Answer (score 0):

prtContent.innerHTMLwill be null as you are using Print instead of 'Print'

```
        function CallPrint() {
        var prtContent = document.getElementById('Print');
        var htmlcontent = prtContent.innerHTML;
        var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=400,height=400,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
        WinPrint.document.write(htmlcontent);
        WinPrint.document.close();
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
    }
```

Comment: now it is working but i have another problem,the problem is a Literal indicates my dynamic table,but print output is just wtih the number i couldnt get my table design.Can you please help